# Mixing acts_as_tree (ancestry gem), acts_as_list and default model scoping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-plugins, named-scope

I'm using the [ancestry gem](http://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) to structure some groups in a tree. At the same time I'm using acts_as_list to keep groups at the same tree level in a sorted list. Given the following model:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_tree
  acts_as_list :scope => "ancestry"

  named_scope :parentable, :conditions => "NOT type = 'PriceGroup'"
  named_scope :without, lambda { |ids| { :conditions => ['id NOT IN (?)', ids] }}

  default_scope :order => "groups.position ASC, groups.name ASC"
end
```

This worked pretty much as intended, eg I use `@group.path` to generate a breadcrumb navigation at the top of the admin interface. The generated SQL is okay, the breadcrumbs are sorted by tree depth as they should. At least this is true for the development environment.

In production it looks completely different: Tracing the generated SQL I found that not ancestry's `path` is generating the result order but instead my `default_scope` takes over.

So I fixed my model to ignore the default scope by overwriting `path`:

```
# remove default scope to not change path sorting
def path
  self.class.send :with_exclusive_scope do
    super
  end
end
```

But while this removed the position scoping from my `default_scope` in development it still is completely ignored in production. Tracing the SQL in production, I don't see ancestry's depth ordering, but instead the position ordering from my `default_scope`.

**Update:** Since my original idea of "patching" the `path` method was somewhat silly (knock knock: it's not inherited, it's dynamically defined), I tried the following still to no avail:

```
# remove default scope to not change path sorting
def path_with_exclusive_scope
  self.class.send :with_exclusive_scope do
    path_without_exclusive_scope
  end
end
alias_method_chain :path, :exclusive_scope
```

When calling `path` in development the generated SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT *
 FROM "groups"
 WHERE ("groups"."id" IN (5,64))
 ORDER BY (case when ancestry is null then 0 else 1 end), ancestry
```

Compared to that here's the generated SQL in production:

```
SELECT *
 FROM `groups`
 WHERE (`groups`.`id` IN (8,49))
 ORDER BY groups.position ASC, groups.name ASC
```

Development uses SQLite where production uses MySQL - but I don't think that is the crucial difference here.

Answer (score 1):

`acts_as_list` has some [bugs](https://github.com/rails/acts_as_list/pull/11) in handling default_scope. You should either avoid using it or look for fixed version on GitHub. Try [this version](https://github.com/MissingHandle/acts_as_list) (you can find a link to the relevant commit in the pull request I've linked earlier)

Comment: Which gem do you suggest instead of acts_as_list for rails 3?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using the scope method, I found this on the ancestry wiki.

```
  has_ancestry :cache_depth =>true
  acts_as_list :scope => 'ancestry = \'#{ancestry}\''
  named_scope :ordered, :order => "ancestry_depth,position DESC"
```

https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry/wiki/arrange_as_array